# How do I get Java support on Google Chrome in Linux?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, java

Is there a way to run Linux Google Chrome with Java support?

Comment: **Moderator note:** I've removed answers that are now obsolete, since Chrome 35 [has dropped NPAPI support](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-dev/xEbgvWE7wMk) and the methods posted here [will all not work](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=379425). We're generally not removing old answers in case people still want to run old stable versions of software, but with Chrome, this is not really feasible nor practical. Looking forward to answers that consider the latest version, therefore making this community wiki to encourage joint efforts.

Comment: Related question on Ask Ubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/470594/how-do-i-get-java-plugin-working-on-google-chrome

Comment: Afaik and also according to https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/qPiZkcLwFFk there is no way to support Java on recent Google Chrome for Linux releases. So switch to Firefox or use - carefuly - an older version of Chrome.

Comment: The information on http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/chrome.xml is a bit confusing, but it seems to be suggesting that you need 64-bit Chrome and 64-bit Java 7 to run Java in Linux. (It claims that Chrome doesn't have a 64-bit Linux version, but [that is false](http://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel)).

Comment: Another thing I haven't tested, so I won't use as an answer: what happens if you run Chrome in Wine? Does the Windows Java 7 plugin work there? If so, there are projects to get plugins that work in Windows to run in Linux browsers. One is used to get Netflix working, for example. (This is mainly a suggestion to help people find an answer.)

Comment: @slhck, Instead of complete deletion, might have been better to just individually [edit out](http://superuser.com/a/902576/78897) the answers so at least we can have an archive of the posts (for research/log/reference purposes).

Comment: @Pacerier That would have made sense if it was just one answer, but here we're talking about multiple ones that would have to be edited. Also, editing a post to completely change its meaning is discouraged. I know it's definitely a solution to say "Update: This doesn't work anymore", but we're trying to give up-to-date and relevant information. Keeping (now) irrelevant stuff for research purposes hasn't really been a goal of these sites.

Answer (score 1):

There's a guy (Michael Müller) who have wrote some patches to re enable the support for NPAPI (so icedtea will work).

This is somewhat a workaround. but is expected to work. (Actually I haven't tested)

Currently the build version is 36.

If you use ArchLinux you can build and install it from AUR. [chromium-npapi](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/chromium-npapi/)

If not, you can see in [PKGBUILD](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ch/chromium-npapi/PKGBUILD) the build process.

Answer (score -3):

try installing icedtea in linux.
it works like a charm.

for Ubuntu

`apt-get install icedtea`

Comment: Does this actually work on Chrome 35 or newer?

Comment: this doesn't work. ref: http://superuser.com/questions/44827/how-do-i-get-java-support-on-google-chrome-in-linux#comment1017389_44827