# Why can't I see Java applets in Chrome after installation of jdk and flashplayer?

Tags: linux, debian, flash-player, java-applet

I installed both `jdk` and `flashplayer`.

For example, when I visit [this Java applet test site](http://www.w3.org/People/mimasa/test/object/java/Othello), this message appears.

> "Missing plug-in".

I have in my `/opt/jdk1.7.0_01/jre/lib/amd64/`

the file `libjavaplugin_jni.so`.

I linked it in  `/opt/google/chrome` and run the browser with --enable-plugins option, but the plugin it seems to be not loaded.

How can I fix tjis?

Comment: I think the problem is for Java applet. But I don't know how to resolve it. I use Debian, and I read that probably I have to put a flashplugin file into the chrome plugin folder. But nothing change!

Comment: Maybe have a look here: [How do I get Java support on Google Chrome in Linux?](http://superuser.com/questions/44827/how-do-i-get-java-support-on-google-chrome-in-linux)

Comment: For example if I'm going on a site where is a Java applet, the applet is not loading but there is a message that says: "Missing plug-in".

Comment: I'm going to watch what do you posted me and I let you know. thanks.

Comment: ok, if I do this test http://www.w3.org/People/mimasa/test/object/java/Othello

"Missing plug-in" appears.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to install chromium and java from debian?

You could use java and chromium from stable by installing chromium-browser and icedtea6-plugin packages, chromium-browser is quite old, but is chromium from debian.

Or you could use package from testing: (if you already use testing or unstable just install the needed package)

Go to http://jaqque.sbih.org/kplug/apt-pinning.html for configuration of mixed stable/testing installation. then

```
apt-get install chromium/testing
```

will install a recent chromium as a Debian package and

```
apt-get install default-jre/testing
apt-get install icedtea-plugin/testing
```

and java should work.

Note the current (15.0.874.106~r107270-1) chromium from unstable is badly broken, don't try to install it.

Answer (score 0):

Google chrome v.35 dropped support to java.

My suggestion, for now, is:

- downgrade to chrome v.34
- install firefox

--

Download site: 
http://mirror.pcbeta.com/google/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/

Answer (score -2):

you need a java applet, if you are using WinOS then Check your control panel if there's a Java there, or else try to download it @ java.com I forgot the name of java, to run it to your Firefox or Chrome...or try to use Firefox first because I already tried running Games or GUI based in Firefox...

Comment: The OP is on Linux.

Comment: try this one 
https://www.google.com/search?sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&client=ubuntu&hs=fRS&channel=fs&source=hp&q=java+applet+for+linux&pbx=1&oq=java+applet+for+linux&aq=f&aqi=g4&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=2595605l2598758l0l2598928l21l10l0l0l0l1l999l3933l5-1.4l5l0&biw=1280&bih=608&cad=cbv&sei=ezbKTpSLNrPTiAK5tcgF

Comment: This problem is under Debian.