# How to get Java working in Chromium (not Google Chrome) for Linux

Tags: linux, browser, java, chromium

A simple question, similar to [another](https://superuser.com/questions/44827/how-do-i-get-java-support-on-google-chrome-in-linux/135487#135487), but the previous answers seem to only apply to Google Chrome.

I have the correct version of IcedTea enabled and no other Java plug-in installed. Even if I run chromium-browser with --enable-plugins, [the Java test page](http://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp?detect=jre) is still not working for me. If it matters, I'm on Linux Mint 15 Cinnamon.

Any suggestions?